# Why always selectedindexchanged is firing when i click on checklistbox dropdownlist in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

tI have one checklistbox dropdownlist which always firing when i click on the dropdown.But I am not selecting any of the listing in the dropdown.How do i fix that.

```
<asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="ddcbProductStockItem" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  
      EnableViewState="true" UseButtons="false" UseSelectAllNode="True"
      CssClass="form-control"
      OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddcbProductStockItem_SelectedIndexChanged">
     <Style SelectBoxWidth="200" DropDownBoxBoxWidth="200" DropDownBoxBoxHeight="130" />
     <Texts SelectBoxCaption="Select Item" />
</asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>
```

In my cs page,

```
if (!IsPostBack)
 {
   binditem();
 }
```

Comment: FYI: I added the asp.net tag to your question to make it clear that it is related to ASP.NET, and not about WinForms or WPF.

Answer (score 1):

try setting AutoPostBack="false"

"AutoPostBack == true && UseButtons == false - no action buttons ( 'OK/Cancel' ) are displayed, postback occurs whenever a user leaves the expanded drop down by clicking outside it."

you can see [here](http://saplin.blogspot.ro/2011/05/dropdowncheckboxes-using-control.html) more details